# Compile a driver made for a newer linux kernel in an older kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

There is a panel driver committed in the kernel 5 of linux kernel. I have a kernel 4.4.

I tried to copy the .c of the new kernel and paste it in my old kernel. Also the Kconfig and Makefile modifications to include it.

But when compiles, it fails in this exact driver, as I saw, the new driver uses different headers apparently the new headers.

The question is whether compiling this driver, for an old kernel, it is something feasible or am I wasting my time?

I attached the compile logs maybe I am missing something. I tried to modify headers too without success, it stills fail compiling.

````
include/drm/drm_modes.h:103:25: error: field 'base' has incomplete type
  struct drm_mode_object base;
                         ^~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:105:12: error: 'DRM_DISPLAY_MODE_LEN' undeclared here (not in a function)
  char name[DRM_DISPLAY_MODE_LEN];
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:150:27: error: field 'picture_aspect_ratio' has incomplete type
  enum hdmi_picture_aspect picture_aspect_ratio;
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:165:27: error: field 'force' has incomplete type
  enum drm_connector_force force;
                           ^~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h: In function 'drm_mode_is_stereo':
include/drm/drm_modes.h:178:23: error: 'DRM_MODE_FLAG_3D_MASK' undeclared (first use in this function)
  return mode->flags & DRM_MODE_FLAG_3D_MASK;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:178:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
include/drm/drm_modes.h: At top level:
include/drm/drm_modes.h:185:49: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:185
 struct drm_display_mode *drm_mode_create(struct drm_device *dev);
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:186:30: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:186
 void drm_mode_destroy(struct drm_device *dev, struct drm_display_mode *mode);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:187:39: warning: 'struct drm_mode_modeinfo' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:187
 void drm_mode_convert_to_umode(struct drm_mode_modeinfo *out,
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:190:20: warning: 'struct drm_mode_modeinfo' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:190
       const struct drm_mode_modeinfo *in);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:200:46: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:200
 struct drm_display_mode *drm_cvt_mode(struct drm_device *dev,
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:204:46: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:204
 struct drm_display_mode *drm_gtf_mode(struct drm_device *dev,
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:207:54: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:207
 struct drm_display_mode *drm_gtf_mode_complex(struct drm_device *dev,
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:213:51: warning: 'struct videomode' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:213
 void drm_display_mode_from_videomode(const struct videomode *vm,
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:216:15: warning: 'struct videomode' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:216
        struct videomode *vm);
               ^~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:229:52: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:229
 struct drm_display_mode *drm_mode_duplicate(struct drm_device *dev,
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:245:36: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:245
 void drm_mode_prune_invalid(struct drm_device *dev,
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~
include/drm/drm_modes.h:256:42: warning: 'struct drm_device' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
error, forbidden warning:drm_modes.h:256
 drm_mode_create_from_cmdline_mode(struct drm_device *dev,
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c: In function 'st7701_get_modes':
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:269:37: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct drm_connector'
  mode = drm_mode_duplicate(connector->dev, desc_mode);
                                     ^~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c: At top level:
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:291:15: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
error, forbidden warning:panel-sitronix-st7701.c:291
  .get_modes = st7701_get_modes,
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:291:15: note: (near initialization for 'st7701_funcs.get_modes')
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:310:10: error: 'DRM_MODE_TYPE_DRIVER' undeclared here (not in a function)
  .type = DRM_MODE_TYPE_DRIVER | DRM_MODE_TYPE_PREFERRED,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:310:33: error: 'DRM_MODE_TYPE_PREFERRED' undeclared here (not in a function)
  .type = DRM_MODE_TYPE_DRIVER | DRM_MODE_TYPE_PREFERRED,
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c: In function 'st7701_dsi_probe':
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:364:10: error: 'DRM_MODE_CONNECTOR_DSI' undeclared (first use in this function)
          DRM_MODE_CONNECTOR_DSI);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:363:2: error: too many arguments to function 'drm_panel_init'
  drm_panel_init(&st7701->panel, &dsi->dev, &st7701_funcs,
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:9:0:
include/drm/drm_panel.h:138:6: note: declared here
 void drm_panel_init(struct drm_panel *panel);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-sitronix-st7701.c:377:8: error: implicit declaration of function 'drm_panel_of_backlight' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  ret = drm_panel_of_backlight(&st7701->panel);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors```
````

Comment: Consider upgrading your kernel first. See https://kernelnewbies.org/ - you can compile the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/) from its source code - see also https://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks! It is an embedded platform and currently it doesn't have support for newer kernel. But yes I am looking forward to update a newer one.

Comment: To determine if this driver can be updated, you'll need to figure out what other pieces of the kernel must be updated to work together. Start with your first error for example. Where is "drm_mode_object" defined? Nowhere in your version of the kernel? Check if it's in a newer version of one of the libraries this driver depends on. Track down what pieces of the kernel will need updating for your desired update to work. As for if it's feasible, well it's open source so feasibility is up to you and the amount of time you're willing to put in! Good luck!